# Airplay to Ubuntu on a different network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, iphone

I'd like to airplay from my phone to my ubuntu desktop. I've installed XMBC and I think I'd be able to get that to work, except, my desktop and my iphone are on two different networks.

iphone:

```
IP: 49.127.22.35
router: 49.127.31.254
DNS: 130.194.1.99 and 130.194.7.99
Subnet: 255.255.224.0
```

desktop:

```
IP: 130.194.130.230
default route: 130.194.131.254
DNS: 130.194.1.99
Secondary DNS: 130.194.7.99
Subnet: 255.255.252.0
```

I don't have any admin rights over the network. Is there any way I can trick one of my two into thinking they're on the same network as the other? If not, is there a way I can use software to make a virtual network (I remember using Hamachi as a kid to make games work)?

Thirdly, could I put a wireless network card in my desktop, share my internet connection through that, connect my iphone to that wireless, and thereby have them on the same network?

Cheers,
James

Comment: What networks are your phone connected to? WiFi? 3G/4G? Do you have a router or do you just have a single LAN cable going from a modem to your desktop?

Comment: Phone is on WIFI.

Comment: Can you provide the subnet mask of both phone and computer networks?

Comment: Subnets are added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to "trick" either device into thinking they are on the same network. You could, in theory, have both of them connect to the same VPN (hosted elsewhere) which would give them a virtual network that you could use. However, I think it would be easier to [set up a tether](https://askubuntu.com/a/126553) and use the shared interface to set up a simple network.

When you have the tether set up, try running XBMC and see if it can locate the phone. If that doesn't work, you could try the VPN idea or else buy a wireless router or install a wireless card on your desktop so that both can be on the same network.

(I couldn't find out for sure if airplay will only work over wifi or if it will run on other interfaces as well).

Comment: if I tether, will I be using my phone's 3g data? I wouldn't want that.

Comment: It should be sending data straight through the USB cable. It won't be able to connect over 3G for the same reasons why it won't connect over the two networks you mentioned before.

Comment: But isn't tethering sharing my iphone's connection to the desktop?

Comment: Yes, but the connection looks like this: Desktop <-> Phone <-> 3G. Since the data transfer is between the desktop computer and the phone, no data should be going over your 3G network.